# mysql escape not working on server

Tags: php

I made login/register script and on my localhost everything work ok, but when I upload script to server then when I use mysql_real_escape function I get empty string. Why is this function different on localhost and real server. This is my code

```
//functions.php

<?php
   function clean($data){
      return mysql_real_escape_string($data);
   }
?>

//otherFile.php

<?php

   include 'functions.php';
   $user = $_POST['username'];
   $pass = encrypt($_POST['password']);
   $rem = $_POST['remember'];

   $user = clean($user);
   $pass = clean($pass);
   $rem = clean($rem);

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mysql_real_escape_string()` requires a valid database connection to be present (it should be the connection that you're using to insert the cleaned data into the database). If no connection exists, `false` will be returned.

Make sure you have a database connection running.

Comment: Ok, so in my every php file, first I include connection.php which is for mysqli connect, and then functions.php where you can find clean() funtion, so if I first include functions.php then connection.php, will it work?

Comment: If you call `clean()` after you initialize the database connection, it should work.

Comment: @Alen If you are using mysqli, why in gods name are you using `mysql_real_escape_string`?!

Comment: I see your point, but if I put mysqli_real_escape_string then I get empty string, and with mysql_real_escape_string my string is properly ecaped although I use mysqli. I'm still php noob so if you have advice about this, share it with me. @deceze

Comment: @Alen never use a different library's escape function. It is vital that you use the correct one, with a valid database connection

Comment: @Alen Get away from the idea of a global "`clean()`" function, it's fundamentally flawed. Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php and http://kunststube.net/escapism.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
   function clean($data){
      return mysql_real_escape_string($temp);
   }
?>
```

you are passing one variable and return another

Edit
Are you connecting with mysql?
For this function to work,you need mysql_connect,not mysqli_connect.

Use mysqli_real_escape_string
[Doc](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)

Comment: Sorry, it was typo, I edited my question. EDIT Yes, I connect with mysql, I only posted block of code where I think the error is